Generate Excel Files in Databricks using Python and Pyspark
I have a PySpark code running in Databricks. I have a PySpark dataframe with these fields (userid, username, and a few transaction details), and I want to generate an Excel file for each userid. I am using the Python xlsxwriter package to generate Excel files.
Currently, I am running a for loop, filtering based on userid, generating a pandas dataframe for a particular userid, and writing it as an Excel file. This entire process takes a lot of time. Can someone help me optimize this process? I thought of using multiprocessing or multithreading in Python to generate Excel files in parallel.
There are a couple of reasons for using the Python xlsxwriter package instead of going with the Maven library:
I don’t want to use any third-party libraries.
I need to apply some formatting in Excel (like applying colors to a specific row).

You mentioned multithreading so how have you tried to achieve the needful using that? You mentioned that you don't want to use a maven package but you have not mentioned why. You can still achieve colours if you have a template excel,, make a copy and update it using the maven package. Please update your question with what you have tried so far and some code along with what your input and expected outputs look like.
